# How to get rid of backslash and quotes together from JSON data caused by fasterxml.jackson api?

Tags: java, json, regex, mongodb, jackson

Need help with Json data. Tried several ways but somehow I couldn't find any solution.

```
   List<BookInfo> list = new ArrayList<BookInfo>();
   String data = null;
   while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
        BookInfo bs= new BookInfo();
        DBObject dbo = cursor.next();
        ArrayList<DBObject> urlArr = (ArrayList<DBObject>)dbo.get("url"); 
        bs.setUrl(urlArr.toString());
        list.add(bs);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        data = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(list);
   }
   return data;
```

Output getting:

```
  "url": "[ { \"uri\" : \"http://books.info/science\"} , { \"uri\" : \"http://books.info/western\"}]"
```

The output should be:

```
    "url": [ { "uri" : "http://books.info/science"}, { "uri" : "http://books.info/western"}]
```

need to get rid of the access double quotes and back slash. Returning the JSON data creating extra double quotes and back slash because of fasterxml.jackson api. Any one knows how to avoid that?

Comment: provide your code, expected and current output, or you'll get downvotes all week :)

Comment: Please show us the things that you tried that did not work.  Also, we need to know whether the _string you are processing_ is the entire key-value pair you've shown, or just the text of the value (without the outer double quotes).

Comment: How about `text = text.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"")` ?

Comment: I'm not a very experienced programmer. I'm working and learning. So some of the part is difficult for me. I'm trying my best to cope up.

Comment: Please reopen it or at least give me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this problem is because first parameter of `replaceAll` is not a string, but a regular expression. Backslash is a [regex meta character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) which means that it needs to be escaped.

It might be confusing as backslash is also Java special character and needs to be escaped again.

```
"\\" - single backslash
"\\\\" - single backslash in regex
"\\\\\\\\" - two backslashes in regex
```

In other words, you have 2 backslashes so regex matching it would be 4 backslashes. But then this regex is written in Java so all 4 backslashes need to be escaped making it 8 backslashes. And that followed by a double quote `\"` giving a nice sequence of 9 backslashes.

Try this code:

```
String s = "\\\\\"test";    // the actual String is: \\"test
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\\"", "\""));
```

Comment: If you need any more than `"\\\\\\\\"` (literal `"\\"` string in Java regex), it might be better to use quoting blocks, with `\Q`  and `\E` instead of a cascade of escape characters. In this case's example: `System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\Q\\\\E\"", "\""));` which will be equivalent to the literal string `\\"` in Java regex the same way and with the same length as `\\\\\\\\\"`.

Comment: Actually, it would be `"\\Q\\\\\\E\""` which is not much better. `\\Q...\\E` are to escape regex meta characters, but you still need two backslashes escaped as java special characters (i.e. 4 backslashes between `\\Q` and `\\E`).

Comment: You're right, I forgot Java's escapes inside the regex quoting block. However, in relation to *"(...) which is not much better"*, my intent was not about this case specifically, but as advice in general, and my point still stands: If you have a cascade of a lot of regex escape characters, there will be a point were it's better to use regex quoting blocks, for increased readability and reduced length.